# k8s: Use parameterized image tag when creating deployment

Tags: shell, deployment, kubernetes

I want to run a `kubernetes` deployment in the likes of the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: our-own-registry.com/somerepo/my-app:${IMAGE_TAG}
        env:
        - name: FOO
          value: "BAR"
```

This will be delivered to the developers so that they can perform on demand deployments using the image tag of their preference.

What is best way / recommended pattern to pass the tag variable?

performing an export on the command line to make it available as env var on the shell from which the `kubectl` command will run?

Comment: There are many ways to this. There is [helm](https://helm.sh/). There is [ksonnet](https://ksonnet.io/). If you, say on windows and use octopus for deployment you can use it for transforming the vars, etc. There is no "the right" answer use what is appropriate for you. if [envsubst](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) works for you, by all means, use envsubst. I've even heard of people who do this with ansible/jinja!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's impossible via native kubernetes tools. From [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52787):

> kubectl will never support variable substitution.

But, that issue case also has some good workarounds. The best way is deploy your apps via `Helm` [charts using templates](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/)

Comment: Helm is just a huge sudo server in your kubernetes cluster. One can _hardly_ call it "the best way". It's one of the ways, alright.

Comment: Actually, `Helm` is something more and you are free to lock down everything you want with RBAC, but it is another case. I really think the `Helm` is much better, then sed/Ansible/jinja or something else, don't you?

Comment: Of course not. For example in OP case the security risk and overhead of managing helm may be just too costly to satisfy quite simple requirements.

Comment: Of course, it will take some time, but `ksonnet` will do the same

Answer (score 0):

For simple use cases [envsubst](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) will do just fine:

```
IMAGE_TAG=1.2 envsubst < deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -`
```